# Symfony3 Language switch in Twig

Tags: twig, symfony, symfony-3.1

Gretings, I have a problem with changing languages from Twig template.
My goal is to make it possible for user to switch page language according to his needs. I did everything according instruction: 
[Making the Locale "Sticky" during a User's Session](http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html)

My question is, **how to change language, which is stored in session, from Twig template?**

My best guess was:

```
{{ app.session.set('_lang', 'en') }}
```

But result was, that language change needed page to be refreshed twice to show results, one to set values in session, second to load page according language stored in session. Please advise!

Comment: have you tried the jms/i18n-routing-bundle ? worked well when i tried it

Comment: Thanks for advise, but I prefer not to use it.

Comment: You have to get current route with params, change/add `_language` parameter for every languages, something like: `{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'),
   app.request.query.all|merge({'_language': 'en'})) }}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution was creating locale prefixes for all controllers and as malcolm offered, using route params:

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.query.all|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to get the route and the route's parameters without knowing them. Then it will override the _locale parameter with your value.

In Twig :

```
{{path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'),app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}
```

With the HTML/Bootstrap code

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="language_switcher" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="language_switcher">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'),app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'ru'})) }}"><span class="flag flag-ru"> </span>  Russian</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'),app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}"><span class="flag flag-us"> </span>  English</a>
    </div>
</li>
```